# Do clubs in Hong Kong have any particular dress code?

Tags: regulations, clothing, hong-kong, nightlife, dress-codes

I'm going to Hong Kong for Easter this year and I needed some packing advice. Do clubs in Hong Kong have a dress code, if any? What I mean by this is for, say, many clubs in London (and here I mean the drinking and dancing type) require 'proper' shoes/shirts. (Which isn't necessarily true for clubs in other cities in England.) The reason I need to know is because I usually travel only with cabin luggage, but if I need to carry additional clothes then I might have to go with a larger piece of luggage and have to check it in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While sites like Wikitravel don't seem to help too much in this case, fortunately we can look at anecdotal evidence and quotes on VirtualTourist [pages](http://www.virtualtourist.com/travel/Asia/Hong_Kong/Nightlife-Hong_Kong-Night_Clubs-BR-1.html) like [these](http://www.virtualtourist.com/travel/Asia/Hong_Kong/Nightlife-Hong_Kong-MISC-BR-1.html).

Quotes from these pages for a selection of clubs:

> "Dress Code: No jeans or sneakers/trainers, must be very fashionable."
>
> "Dress Code: No Jeans , shorts, or flip flops !!!!"
>
> "Dress Code: Just don't look like a COPLETE MUPPET !!" (sic)
>
> "Dress Code: Dress to kill, place is Ultra HIP !!!!!"
>
> "Dress Code: Casual Chic, everyone's an expat or a chuppie (chinese
>   yuppie) over here."
>
> "Dress Code: Dress like a rich hobbit. The place here is small and the
>   food/drinks come at a price."
>
> "Dress Code: Trendy and stylish "
>
> "Dress Code: I dont know that there is a dress code but we did have
>   proper evening attire on and fit right in."
>
> "Dress Code: Your with the movers and shakers of the Hong Kong world
>   !!!!! Dress to Impress is the word !!!!!"
>
> "Dress Code: Cool lounge wear - jeans are fine, flip flops are not
>   noticeable but dress cool"

So it sounds like for a lot of them, smart-casual is the plan, and given there's some suggestion of style and smartening-up, personally I'd pack town shoes.

Comment: One of my friend was rejected because he tried to enter a club dress formal after work.

Comment: Hmm, so wearing jeans is starting to sound like a risky plan. :/

Comment: I'd hunt around on that site and look at some of the bars - you may find some that look appealing that have a more relaxed code. Or even just ask people when you get there where they'd recommend.  If backpackers can still go out in town, there must be some place ;)